# Light monitoring of local https services with mon?

Tags: monitoring, https

I'm running mon as a secondary monitoring system. It's clean and simple --an excellent backup monitoring system.
It has some built-in monitors but not one for https.

Is there a way to quickly and easily monitor internal https services?

Answer (score 0):

I found a community contributed https monitor for the mon service.
It's available [individually](http://ftp.kernel.org/pub/software/admin/mon/contrib/index.html) or in the mon-contrib package. Follow this link for the https.service [readme](http://ftp.kernel.org/pub/software/admin/mon/contrib/monitors/https/https.monitor.README).
I installed like so:

```
sudo apt-get mon-contrib
```

The monitor is called from the mon config file:

```
/etc/mon/mon.cf
```

I call the monitor with all three supported options
port, timeout and url

```
watch my_hostgroup
        service https
                description my service
                interval 2m
                monitor https.monitor -p 10443 -t 60 -u /api/heartbeat
                period
                        numalerts 2
                        alertafter 1m
                        alert mail.alert my@email.address
```

You can test it at the command line with:

```
/usr/lib/mon/mon.d/https.monitor -v -p 10443 -t 60 -u /api/heartbeat hostname.domain.name
```